# Alias for long list name and modification

Tags: python, data-structures, alias, naming, mutable

I have a **nested data structure** (e.g. mydict[names[num]]) which is **difficult to read in code**. Hence I would like to create a **proxy (alias)** and use it to modify this structure.

```
long_name = [1,2,3]
short = long_name
assert id(long_name) == id(short)

short.append(4)
assert id(long_name) == id(short)

short = [n**2 for n in short]
assert id(long_name) == id(short)  # AssertionError
```

Given the **AssertionError on id(a) = id(b)**, do I understand correctly python separates short and long_name during comprehension and allocates **separate memory?**

In practice, my structure contains millions of long strings, so takes up a lot of space (memory), hence this concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When **long_name** and **short** are associated with the same object, you can call its methods as many times as you like and both variables will not change, but **comprehension** will create a new object and you will link your **short** variable to it. Now you have 2 variables associated with 2 different objects and 2 different links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).